# Emacs-lisp callbacks

Tags: rest, url, elisp

In Emacs 27.1, the following code gives me a `(void-variable buffer)` error in the callback.  Are closures not supported in elisp?

```
(defun make-callback (buffer)
  (lambda (status)
    (message "buffer: %s" buffer)))


(defun make-rest-call ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((buffer (current-buffer))
         (callback (make-callback buffer))
         (url "some-url")
         (url-request-method "POST")
         (url-request-extra-headers 
           `(("Content-Type" . "application/json")))
         (url-request-data (json-encode ...)))
    (url-retrieve url callback)))
```

Comment: There will be many duplicates for this question, but I didn't have time to locate a good one.  The short answer is that you need to enable lexical binding for your elisp file.  Read `C-h i g (elisp)Converting to Lexical Binding`.  Without this, your `buffer` argument has dynamic scope, and is only bound while the inner lambda is being *defined*, not when it's subsequently called.

Comment: If you don't wish to enable lexical-binding, you can alternatively use quasi-quoting and evaluation to hard-code the buffer value in the function: `(defun make-callback (buffer) \`(lambda (status) (message "buffer: %s" ,buffer)))`

Comment: @phils: Unfortunately, the other questions have very dated answers ranked high and the solution I finally used is ranked near the bottom without any explanation. Certain sections of the official elisp documentation on closures found online makes it sound like it should work out of the box.  Your clear explanation of the problem and pointer to the right documentation made all the difference.

Answer (score 2):

phils explains that lexical binding needs to be explicitly enabled.  Otherwise the `buffer` argument has dynamic scope, and is bound only when the inner lambda is defined, and not when it is invoked.

Using the documentation phils recommended: Adding the following line to the top of the elisp file to set the buffer-local variable `lexical-binding` fixed the problem.

```
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```